# Problem with Web Scraping to CSV [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to build an automated web scraper, and I have spent hours watching YT videos and reading stuff here. New to programming (started one month ago) and new to this community...

So, using VScode as my IDE, I followed the format of this code (python and selenium) that actually worked as a web scraper:

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

with open('job_scraping_multipe_pages.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write("Job_title, Location, Salary, Contract_type, Job_description \n")
    
driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.jobsite.co.uk/')

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

cookie= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="accept-button-new"]')
try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass 

job_title=driver.find_element_by_id('keywords')
job_title.click()
job_title.send_keys('Software Engineer')
time.sleep(1)

location=driver.find_element_by_id('location')
location.click()
location.send_keys('Manchester')
time.sleep(1)

dropdown=driver.find_element_by_id('Radius')
radius=Select(dropdown)
radius.select_by_visible_text('30 miles')
time.sleep(1)

search=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Search"]')
search.click()
time.sleep(2)

for k in range(3):
    titles=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="job-title"]/a/h2')
    location=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="location"]/span')
    salary=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@title="salary"]')
    contract_type=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="job-type"]/span')
    job_details=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@title="job details"]/p')

    with open('job_scraping_multipe_pages.csv', 'a') as file:
        for i in range(len(titles)):
            file.write(titles[i].text + "," + location[i].text + "," + salary[i].text + "," + contract_type[i].text + ","+
                      job_details[i].text + "\n")

        
        next=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@aria-label="Next"]')
        next.click()
    file.close()
driver.close()
```

---

It worked. I then tried to replicate the results for another website. Instead of hitting the 'next' button, I was able to find a way to cause the ending number of the URL increase by 1. But my problems came from the last parts of the code, giving me **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'**. Here is the code for the *website I was targeting* (https://angelmatch.io/pitch_decks/5285) in Python and Selenium:

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


with open('pitchDeckResults2.csv', 'w' ) as file:
    file.write("Startup_Name, Startup_Description, Link_Deck_URL, Startup_Website, Pitch_Deck_PDF, Industries, Amount_Raised, Funding_Round, Year /n")




    for k in range(5285, 5287, 1):
        
        linkDeck = "https://angelmatch.io/pitch_decks/" + str(k)        

        driver.get(linkDeck)
        driver.maximize_window
        time.sleep(2)

        startupName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
        startupDescription = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/p[2]')
        startupWebsite = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[3]/a')
        pitchDeckPDF = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/button/a')
        industries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[2]')
        amountRaised = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[1]/b')
        fundingRound = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[1]')
        year = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[2]/b')

        

        with open('pitchDeckResults2.csv', 'a') as file:
            for i in range(len(startupName)):
                file.write(startupName[i].text + "," + startupDescription[i].text + "," + linkDeck[i].text + "," + startupWebsite[i].text + "," + pitchDeckPDF[i].text + "," + industries[i].text + "," + amountRaised[i].text + "," + fundingRound[i].text + "," + year[i].text +"\n")

            time.sleep(1)

        file.close()

driver.close()
```

I'll appreciate any help! I am trying to get the data into CSV using this technique!

Comment: I have updated code, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you're doing great, honestly. The only thing and why error appears, you're trying to get **.text** variable from string type value. str type in python doesn't have any text variable.
Moreover you're trying to iterate it by **[i]** what can reach 'list index out of range.' exception.
What you're trying to put on the place of linkDeck[i].text, might be page.title?or what?

By the way, you shouldn't close file when you use with open() statement.
It's context manager, which makes it without you after you leave file out

add added columns to maxamize_window() and remove 1 file opening, and added just link:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
delimeter = ';'
with open('pitchDeckResults2.csv', 'w+') as _file:
    _l = ['Startup_Name', 'Startup_Description', 'Link_Deck_URL', 'Startup_Website', 'Pitch_Deck_PDF', 'Industries',
          'Amount_Raised', 'Funding_Round', 'Year \n']
    _file.write(delimeter.join(_l))
    for k in range(5285, 5287, 1):
        linkDeck = "https://angelmatch.io/pitch_decks/" + str(k)

        driver.get(linkDeck)
        time.sleep(1)

        startupName = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
        startupDescription = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/p[2]')
        startupWebsite = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[3]/a')
        pitchDeckPDF = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/button/a')
        industries = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[2]')
        amountRaised = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[1]/b')
        fundingRound = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[1]')
        year = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[2]/b')

        all_elements = [startupName.text, startupDescription.text, linkDeck, startupWebsite.text, pitchDeckPDF.text,
                        industries.text, amountRaised.text, fundingRound.text, f"{year.text}\n"]
        _str = delimeter.join(all_elements)
        _file.write(_str)

driver.close()
```

Might I have missed smth, let me know

Comment: I am trying to create a CSV file with nine columns labeled "Startup_Name, Startup_Description, Link_Deck_URL, Startup_Website, Pitch_Deck_PDF, Industries, Amount_Raised, Funding_Round, Year"

Comment: **I am trying to create a CSV file with nine columns, each titled "Startup_Name, Startup_Description ... Funding_Round, Year."** What boggles me is that the original code I am trying to replicate works. As you noted, it may be that startupName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]') ... does not actually get a text element from the website I am scraping ... linkDeck in file.write stands for the page URL that increases by 1 every next page. the file.write section represents the data I am scraping under their respective titles... Appreciate it...

Comment: the top section of the code, where I create the titles for the columns works well, but the file.write(startupName[i].text + "," + ... part is where it fails and gives the error message.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you updated it... let me try...

Comment: Yes! It worked! Now I just need to fix the formatting because some of it comes out weirdly in terms of Excel formatting. I noticed that you changed "w" to "w+" and removed the [i] (which makes sense since I am already looping with k?)... what is the difference between "w" and "w+"? Now, I don't want to hold you here, but any suggestions on fixing the excel format? (perhaps me using Xpaths is the reason for the issues?)

Comment: @JGNT you made 98%, I just added tricky things, if I'm not mistaken w+ just added opportunity to create file, if it's not exists. I would suggest using more relative selectors, and also use smth like ",".join(list with your elements). you should add + "," +

Comment: I realized that the formatting issue was caused because Excel read commas as delimiters (when scraping the data, some of it had commas)... Do you know how I can tell the code to set the delimiter to ";" instead? I don't know where to add such an indication.

Comment: @JGNT where do you use Excel, sorry?

Comment: @JGNT you can set delimeter on the step of writing data, when you read it, you just split and read by lines

Comment: when I run the code, it should create an Excel (an app that can read CSV) file in your C//:Users/YourName folder. Sorry for asking such basic questions, but I know there is a way to set the delimiter when creating the CSV file... If not, how can I read it correctly? Every time there is a comma, the program splits the words at the wrong time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229971/discussion-between-vova-and-jgnt).